# How to keep a label updated with the content of a variable?

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that has a form on the main monitor and another on a secondary one.

I want to keep the content of a label in the secondary form updated with the value of a variable in the main form.

Right now I'm doing it with a timer in the secondary form that reads the variable from the main form and updates the label content when the variable changes, but I wanted to know if there is a better way for doing this, without the timer that's working all the time.

Comment: Why not use the event "OnTextChanged" of your label on the main form to update your other form ?

Comment: The "clean" way to do this is to use WPF which supports the MVVM model, and bind the label text to an observable property of your model.

Answer (score 2):

The source of the event (variable changing its value) is the primary form. So it is its duty to notify every external entity (the second form) that this value has been changed.

Following this line of thought you should implement an event in the primary form and let other entity subscribe to this event to be notified when the variable changes

In Form1 (the main form)

```
public delegate void OnVeryImportantValueChanged(int newValue);
public event OnVeryImportantValueChanged ImportantValueChanged;
```

when you change the value of your important value, check if someone has subscribed to the event, and if positive, call the event handler

```
importantValue = CalculateNewValue();
if(ImportantValueChanged != null) 
    ImportantValueChanged(importantValue);
```

In Form2 (the secondary form)

```
Form1 newForm1 = new Form1();
newForm1.ImportantValueChanged += ReceiveNotificationForChange;
newForm1.Show();

public void ReceiveNotificationForChange(int newValue)
{
    label.Text = "NewValue received:" + newValue.ToString();
}
```

In the above scenario, the Form2 opens the Form1, but if this is not the case (It is Form1 that opens Form2) then the process requires that you pass  the instance of Form1 inside the constructor of Form2 and use that instance to wire the event

In Form1

```
 Form2 newForm2 = new Form2(this);
 newForm2.Show();
```

in the constructor of Form2

```
 public void Form2(Form1 callerInstance)
 {
      InitializaComponents();
      callerInstance.ImportantValueChanged += ReceiveNotificationForChange;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main form code, instead of using a variable to store your value, use a property which automatically sets the label:

```
private string _value;
private string Value {
  get { return _value; }
  set { 
    _value = value;
    if (secondForm != null) secondForm.lblValue.Text = value;
  }
}
```

Then when you set the value in your main form, do it with `Value = "blah blah";`, and the property setter will change the label for you.

Comment: I admit this is subjective, but "pushing" data around like this quickly leads to spaghetti code. Forms arguably shouldn't "own" data to begin with, much less propagate it to other forms.

Comment: @millimoose I agree with you, this is not the design I would use.. but it is a simple way to implement the question as asked.